# Redux action not firing - no errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm trying to call a simple action on click which fires a dispatch action. I can't seem to get a result or even indiciation that it's firing.

I'm trying to dispatch on click in a component. I've also tried putting a console.log in the action to see if it even gets fired but it doesn't. Redux dev tools also doesn't suggest it even gets fired on click.

```
onClick={() => {
   setAQIType(name);
}}
```

Action:

```
import { SET_AQITYPE } from "./types";

export const setAQIType = (AQIType) => dispatch => {
    dispatch({
        type: SET_AQITYPE,
        payload: { AQIType }
    });
};
```

Reducer:

```
import { SET_AQITYPE } from '../actions/types';

const initialState = {
    aqiType: 'DEFAULT',
    loading: false,
};

export default function(state = initialState, action){

    const { type, payload } = action;

    switch(type){
        case SET_AQITYPE:
            return [...state, payload];
        default:
            return state;
    }

}
```

Types:

```
export const SET_AQITYPE = 'SET_AQITYPE';
```

Comment: Did you use `mapStatetoProps` and `mapDispatchtoProps` with `connect`? Because you shild bind your actions with dispatch and use it as `this.props.setAQIType(name);`

Comment: are you using mapDispatchToProps ? please read the docs: see this: https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react

Comment: have u try to console.log(state) in reducer, to make sure dispatch action it's worked.
if console success print state, please edit and add state mapping in your component

Comment: I have mapStateToProps but not mapDispatchtoProps so i guess this is what im missing, in addition to @Joseph D answer. I'll have a read! Thank you

Comment: ```mapStateToProps``` fetches data from reducer. ```mapDispatchToProps``` dispatches your action through action creator to reducer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three errors,

1. In reducer: Your state is an `object` and not a list.
2. In reducer: Assign payload to `aqiType` key
3. In dispatch: Payload is a string and not an object.

To fix:

```
export const setAQIType = (AQIType) => dispatch => {
    dispatch({
        type: SET_AQITYPE,
        payload: AQIType // (3) pass as string
    });
};

// In reducer
case SET_AQITYPE:
  return { // (1) object
    ...state,
    aqiType: payload // (2) specify aqiType key
  };
```

*This assumes that you've checked the [basic example](https://redux.js.org/basics/example) with `connect()` and `mapDispatchToProps`.*

Comment: Thank you. I've made the changes but still couldn't get it to work. Someone else suggested mapDispatchToProps also so i'll have a read! :) Thank you!

Comment: @StephanieParker check out the basic example link in my post to see how to make it work.

Comment: @StephanieParker I think you need to import redux-thunk if you want to use dispatch in your action. otherwise return directly your action object

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you missed to connect the component with the redux store, which means there is no dispatch function passed to your action.

https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch

Cheers

Comment: Any questions to the OP should be a comment.

Comment: Ok I'm sorry :-)

Answer (score -1):

Try to `return` inside action function as below:

```
import { SET_AQITYPE } from "./types";

export const setAQIType = (AQIType) => dispatch => {
    return dispatch({
        type: SET_AQITYPE,
        payload: { AQIType }
    });
};
```

Comment: she is not dispatching any action in the react end ! where's mapDispatchToProps ?